# Surfaces of non-constant negative curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Are there any nice models or books/papers with elementary discussions of surfaces with non-constant negative curvature, but negative everywhere, analogous to the Poincare disk for constant negative curvature.  I'm particularly interested in the structure of horocycles on such spaces.

Comment: check out Eberlein and O'Neill's article 'Visibility Manifolds'  https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102946601